# Taking an image from photo library and uploading to Firebase

Tags: swift3, ios10, firebase-storage

I am trying to take what I have in my photo library (recently taken photo saved in library) and uploaded to Firebase Storage.

Code below is the saving of the image and adding it the the library:

```
// MARK: - Save image

@IBAction func savePhoto(_ sender: Any) {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(licensePhoto.image!, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
}


//MARK: - Add image to Library

func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if let error = error {
        // we got back an error!
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(alert, animated: true)
    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Image saved successfully", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

I have tried the following code, only to give me an error of:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value after signing up!:

Code:

```
    // . . .  upload license photo to firebase
    

    var data = NSData()
    data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(licensePhoto.image!, 0.8)! as NSData
    // set upload path
    let filePath = "\(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)/\("userPhoto")"
    let metaData = FIRStorageMetadata()
    metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"
    DataService.Instance.storageRef.child(filePath).put(data as Data, metadata: metaData){(metaData,error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }else{
            //store downloadURL
            let downloadURL = metaData!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString
            //store downloadURL at database
            DataService.Instance.dbRef.child("users").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).updateChildValues(["userPhoto": downloadURL])
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include your code as text and not as image, otherwise copying and modifying it is a lot harder.

Comment: Sorry about that, I will edit it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer:

```
  // . . .  upload license photo to firebase

    let storage = FIRStorage.storage().reference()
    let tempImgRef = storage.child("tmpDir/tmpImage.jpg")

    var data: NSData = NSData()
    data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(licensePhoto.image!, 0.8)! as NSData

    let metaData = FIRStorageMetadata()
    metaData.contentType = "image/jpeg"

    tempImgRef.put(data as Data, metadata: metaData, completion: { (metaData, error) in
        if error == nil {
            print("success")

        } else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
        }
    })
}
```